# Javascript and code behind issue (vb.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender with a form.
In that panel, I have a HTML select:

```
<select id="mem_size_ddl" name="mem_size_ddl">
  <option value="NULL">Empty</option>
  <option value="512 MB">512 MB</option>
  <option value="1 GB">1 GB</option>
  <option value="2 GB">2 GB</option>
  <option value="4 GB">4 GB</option>
  <option value="8 GB">8 GB</option>
  <option value="16 GB">16 GB</option>
  <option value="32 GB">32 GB</option>
</select>
```

When the popup is shown, I have a code behind sub that calls data from a database and assigns the value to the dropdown.

So, basically, the idea is to call a javascript function to do it.

I tried all of those with no success (the function is never called):

```
If (Not script.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(cstype, csname)) Then
  script.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, csname, "initmeminfo();", False)
End If

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "alert", "<script type='text/javascript'>initmeminfo();</script>", True)

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "alert", "initmeminfo();", True)

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "alert", "initmeminfo();", True)

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", "initmeminfo();", True)

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "initmeminfo();", True)

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(modalpopup, modalpopup.GetType(), "myFunction", "initmeminfo();", True)
```

So, I added runat="server" to the select tag:

```
<select id="mem_size_ddl" name="mem_size_ddl" runat="server">
```

and tried to assign the value from the code behind directly but that fails too.
Code tested (x2):

```
Dim memsize As DropDownList = CType(Me.FindControl("mem_size_ddl"), DropDownList)
memsize.Items.FindByValue(parts(0)).Selected = True

mem_size_ddl.Items.FindByText(parts(0)).Selected = True
```

With the above codes, the error is:
An HtmlSelect cannot have multiple items selected when Multiple is false.

Anyone able to tell me how to get the javascipt call to work?

Thanks.

Note: I can call ajax functions no problem at all.

Comment: So you want to call a javascript function to fill your dropdown list?  Or you want to call a javascript function from the selection of an item in your dropdown list?

Comment: I need to assign the value to the dropdownlist
      ` function initmeminfo(size) {
            alert('on it');
            var memsize = document.getElementById("mem_size_ddl");
            memsize.selectedIndex = size;
        }`

Comment: Anyone able to help please?

Comment: Why not use a asp:Dropdownlist and fill that with your data from your database?  Set Autopostback to true and you will get your values when the selection is changed?

Comment: Two reasons why I can't use the asp:dropdownlist. 1) I use an Ajax call to populate a database and Javascript/jquery won't have access to an asp: control. 2) that drop-down is a 'static' dropdownlist and a selection change does not trigger anything.

Comment: I found part of the solutionh but it creates another problem.
The code to call the Javascript function is:
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "initmeminfo", "initmeminfo();", True)`
However, for this to work, the javascript is to be placed in the <Head> tag...which known nothing about my dropdown because it has not been initialized yet.
Any idea?